# how do I sort keys of hash alphanumeric with "=" and "."

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a hash which has keys as following:

```
m2-10.10845.857-10.3145.857 
m2-10.3145.857-10.42545.857
m2-10.42545.857-10.62845.857
m2-10.62845.857-10.83645.857
m2-11.60745.857-12.11745.857
m2-7.80945.857-8.01645.857
m2-8.01645.857-8.13145.857
m2-8.13145.857-8.24645.857
m2-8.24645.857-8.44345.857
m2-8.44345.857-9.7945.857
m2-9.7945.857-9.90545.857
m2-9.90545.857-10.10845.857
```

I want to sort them in a way that they appear as following:

```
m2-11.60745.857-12.11745.857
m2-10.62845.857-10.83645.857
m2-10.42545.857-10.62845.857
m2-10.3145.857-10.42545.857
m2-10.10845.857-10.3145.857
m2-9.90545.857-10.10845.857
m2-9.7945.857-9.90545.857
m2-8.44345.857-9.7945.857
m2-8.24645.857-8.44345.857
m2-8.13145.857-8.24645.857
m2-8.01645.857-8.13145.857
m2-7.80945.857-8.01645.857
```

I tried with

```
foreach my $key(sort {$h{$a} cmp $h{$b} } keys %h){
  printf FHOUT "$h{$key}\n";
}
```

But it did not work. How do I do this?

**Update:**
Just came up with a solution:

```
my @keys = sort{substr($h{$a},3,8) <=> substr($h{$b},3,8) } keys %h;
print "$_\n" for @keys;
```

But, how can make it more generic?

Comment: How does it come out? What's not working? Please [edit] your question and include how it's wrong.

Comment: It came out as: `m2-10.10845.857-10.3145.857
m2-10.3145.857-10.42545.857
m2-10.42545.857-10.62845.857
m2-10.62845.857-10.83645.857
m2-11.60745.857-12.11745.857
m2-7.80945.857-8.01645.857
m2-8.01645.857-8.13145.857
m2-8.13145.857-8.24645.857
m2-8.24645.857-8.44345.857
m2-8.44345.857-9.7945.857
m2-9.7945.857-9.90545.857
m2-9.90545.857-10.10845.857`

Comment: [edit] your question with further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples shown in the question sort by comparing *values*, not keys. I will use the statement, to sort by keys.  For simplicity we can think of the problem of sorting an array with given elements.

It seems that you want to sort by the first number, then by the second, then by the third. The second set of numbers (after the second `-`) seems to not matter. Also, as it's always `m2` I'll disregard it.

For sorting by numbers we use numerical sort (`<=>`), not lexicographical (`cmp`).

Then break the first set of numbers into its components and sort

```
foreach my $key ( sort { by_component($a, $b) } (keys %h) ) {
    print "$key\n";
}

sub by_component {
    my ($aa, $bb) = @_; 

    my @num_aa = split /\./, (split /-/, $aa)[1];    #/
    my @num_bb = split /\./, (split /-/, $bb)[1];

    return
        $num_bb[0] <=> $num_aa[0] ||
        $num_bb[1] <=> $num_aa[1] ||
        $num_bb[2] <=> $num_aa[2];
}
```

The `<=>` operator returns `1` if its left operand is greater than the right, `0` if they're equal, or `-1` if right is greater.  Both `1` or `-1` are "true" so the whole expression is true and *that value* is returned. The `0` is false and then the next condition after `||` is evaluated -- we sort by the next number if the first pair is equal.

This prints the desired order of keys.

See [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) and [`<=>` and `cmp` operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators), and [logical operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) for their behavior described above.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect! I just tweaked a bit according to my requirement.

Comment: could you please translate the return statement to English language? To be precise, what is the role of "||" here?

Comment: `||` is the 'or' operator. If you do 'a OR b' then if a is "true" then you don't need to evaluate B - the expression is true. So in a return statement - it processes each statement in order, and if they are 'true' - which in this contexts, means returning _either_ `-1` or `1` (but not zero) then that's the value that's returned. Otherwise it's still not sure if 'or' is true or false, so it has to evaluate the next slice of the expression.

Comment: @tt_pre  It's very late here, so just a comment now. I'll edit later.  The `$x <=> $y` returns `1` if `$x` is greater than `$y`, if the other way round it returns `-1`, and if they are equal a `0`.  If we get `1` or `-1` that is the result (since `||` short-circuits), but if it's `0` that is false and the statement continues to the next condition, after `||`.  So you can chain them like that.

Comment: @Sobrique and zdim Thanks for the explanation. It's clear now.

Comment: From the desired output, it looks to me like it should *not* sort numerically

Comment: @ysth I just noticed (after seeing your comment) that the 4th and 5th line are switched (in the sense of sort I posted) -- is that what you mean?

Comment: That's not how I think of it, but yes.

Comment: @ysth Heh, I don't see how else to sort for the shown desired output; I can imagine a posting error though, since all else fits. Sorting like one does IP's doesn't change the output (and, it's twice-not IPs).  I'll look more, it seems that you have something in mind :)

Comment: Just cmp, not <=>

Answer (score 0):

`sort` takes any function that returns positional comparators for `$a` and `$b`.

I would suggest what you're trying to do is decompose your strings into fields, and compare 'field by field' to sort. I've chosen to 'handle' the string comparison in my example, but as they're all 'm2' prefixed, that's not having any impact on the results. Note - everything is 'descending' order in my example, so 'm1' will be lower down than 'm3', the same as '7' is lower down the order than '11'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub custom_sort {
   my @a_keys = split /[-\.]/, $a;
   my @b_keys = split /[-\.]/, $b;

   #check each key until 'array' is empty. 
   while ( @a_keys and @b_keys ) {
      #if both are numeric, compare numerically.
      if (   $a_keys[0] =~ /^\d+$/
         and $b_keys[0] =~ /^\d+$/ )
      {

         my $comparison = shift @b_keys <=> shift @a_keys;
         #returns a result if it's anything other than '0' e.g. they're the same. 
         return $comparison if $comparison;
      }
      else {
         #compare stringwise. 
         my $comparison = shift @b_keys cmp shift @a_keys;
         return $comparison if $comparison;
      }
   }
   #fell through all the comparisons, so identical. 
   return 0;
}

chomp ( my @values  = <DATA> );
print join ("\n", sort {custom_sort} @values ), "\n";


__DATA__
m2-10.10845.857-10.3145.857 
m2-10.3145.857-10.42545.857
m2-10.42545.857-10.62845.857
m2-10.62845.857-10.83645.857
m2-11.60745.857-12.11745.857
m2-7.80945.857-8.01645.857
m2-8.01645.857-8.13145.857
m2-8.13145.857-8.24645.857
m2-8.24645.857-8.44345.857
m2-8.44345.857-9.7945.857
m2-9.7945.857-9.90545.857
m2-9.90545.857-10.10845.857
```

This works through the value, one 'field' at a time, and compares them - moving onto the next if the 'comparison' is zero (e.g.  they're equal).

Which gives as output:

```
m2-11.60745.857-12.11745.857
m2-10.62845.857-10.83645.857
m2-10.42545.857-10.62845.857
m2-10.10845.857-10.3145.857 
m2-10.3145.857-10.42545.857
m2-9.90545.857-10.10845.857
m2-9.7945.857-9.90545.857
m2-8.44345.857-9.7945.857
m2-8.24645.857-8.44345.857
m2-8.13145.857-8.24645.857
m2-8.01645.857-8.13145.857
m2-7.80945.857-8.01645.857
```